Make another Series with the same index as current Series but with different values
I have
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

s = dd.from_pandas(pd.Series([1,2,3]))

I'm trying to make another Series s_other which should be just like s, but:

all values should be 999
its index should be s.index

I've tried doing the following but it errors:
In [40]: s_other = dd.from_pandas(pd.Series([999]*len(s)))

In [41]: s_other.index = s.index
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[41], line 1
----> 1 s_other.index = s.index

File ~/scratch/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dask_expr/_collection.py:658, in FrameBase.index(self, value)
    656 @index.setter
    657 def index(self, value):
--> 658     assert expr.are_co_aligned(
    659         self.expr, value.expr
    660     ), "value needs to be aligned with the index"
    661     _expr = expr.AssignIndex(self, value)
    662     self._expr = _expr

AssertionError: value needs to be aligned with the index

I'd like to end up with s_other in which:

all values are 999
its length equals the length of s
doing s_other.index = s.index does not raise "value needs to be aligned with the index" (this last step is very important!)


I would do it like this:
s_other = s.copy()

and then set all values of that copy to 999
# Set all values of the Series to 999
s_other[:] = 999

(Another option is to use set_index)
s_other = pandas.DataFrame()
# add values
pandas.s_other.set_index(s.index)

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html

This is a question about Dask, not pandas

Here's something I came up with:
_df = s.to_frame('a')
_df['tmp'] = 999
s_other = _df['tmp']

